# D3: change line stroke color by hovering over legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm sure it's an easy solution. But I can't find it out. I've checked other similar Q&A but they don't fit exactly my problem. 
I just want to highlight a line in my multiline chart when I pass the mouse over the corresponding legend. Probably my mistake is not selecting propperly the lines. I thought I had to use "path", but... I tried with other, but they don't work. Here I attach a pic of my code: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQstf.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Sorry guys, this is my fist time making a question in stackoverflow. Here I attach the code. Basically is a Mike Bostock’s example:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

```
// MARGINS ------------------------------------------------
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;


// SCALES ------------------------------------------------
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

 // AXIS DEFINING ------------------------------------------------
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

 // SCALES ------------------------------------------------
    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.outcome); });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.tsv("datac.tsv", function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;

      color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "year"; }));

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.year = parseDate(d.year);
      });

      var countries = color.domain().map(function(name) {
        return {
          name: name,
          values: data.map(function(d) {
            return {year: d.year, outcome: +d[name]};
          })
        };
      });

      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }));

      y.domain([
        d3.min(countries, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.outcome; }); }),
        d3.max(countries, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.outcome; }); })
      ]);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("");

      var country = svg.selectAll(".country")
          .data(countries)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "country");


      country.append("path")
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });

      country.append("text")
          .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.year) + "," + y(d.value.outcome) + ")"; })
          .attr("x", 3)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; })   
            .on("mouseover", function() {
                d3.select("path")
                   .style("stroke", "red");
             })
           .on("mouseout", function(d) {
               d3.select("path")
                .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
              });  

    });
```

Comment: could you rather post the code instead of a picture ?

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the post rather than linking to it via a picture.

Comment: Try `country.select("path")` instead of `d3.select("path")`. d3.select does not traverse the DOM, so I don't think it finds the line. `d3.selectAll(".line")` might work as well.

Comment: Hi Hugues Stefanski! Thanks! Yeap, both of your options work. Now the point is that those solutions highlight all the lines but what I want is changing only the colour of one line (the one -a country- I hover in the legend). Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hugues mentioned, you need to change your select.  If you want just one line, you need to select that one specific line either by giving an id to the path (or g) or some other ordinal selection.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/s1g2yyru/

For your case, probably try:

```
var country = svg.selectAll(".country")
          .data(countries)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "country")
          .attr('id', function(d) { return d.name.replace(' ',''); });

     country.append("text")
          .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.year) + "," + y(d.value.outcome) + ")"; })
          .attr("x", 3)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; })   
            .on("mouseenter", function() {
                svg.selectAll('#' + d.name.replace(' ','') + ' path').
                   .style("stroke", "red");
             })
           .on("mouseleave", function(d) {
               svg.selectAll('#' + d.name.replace(' ','') + ' path').
                .style("stroke", color(d.name));
              });
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks George! Wow. I think this is a little advance for me. The point is... when I use it with an external tvs file, it doesn't work: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". I took your example (https://jsfiddle.net/s1g2yyru/) and I adapted it: **d.date = parseDate(d.date);** instead of **d.date = parseDate(d.date.toString());** Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I had to replace the reading of the tsv file with a json object (and why I needed to convert the date as a string).

Comment: Yeap, I suppose that George. Wow. I have a lot to learn... What do I have to modify on your example to get it work with an external file? I'm trying several things, but "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" always appears.

Comment: Do what the original code that Mike Bostock provided.  d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) { ...... } );

Comment: Thanks George. I'm still a newie. Now I am reading your suggestion.